# Plot Column from different dataframe into one chart of lines

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have two dataframes with the same headers. I want to plot the 'Close' column from both data frames into one chart of lines.

so I have:

```py
(aapl.Close).plot()
```

and

```py
(tsla.Close).plot()
```

which clearly does what I need to plot but in two different charts. I need two lines in one line chart.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the below, literally after I posted.

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

ax.plot(aapl.Close)
ax.plot(tsla.Close)